# Why can't I add a border on my SVG paths?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I put there my code, i try to add some stroke on the first letter but doesn't work, what can i do? Whats wrong? I try with #logo path:nth-child(). But its the same, the letter doesn't change.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
background-color: black;

}

#logo {
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 20%;
}

#logo path:nth-child(1) {
    stroke-dasharray: 200px;
    stroke-dasharray: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="logo" width="561" height="156" viewBox="0 0 561 156" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <mask id="path-1-outside-1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0.0880127" y="0.440002" width="561" height="156" fill="black">
            <rect fill="white" x="0.0880127" y="0.440002" width="561" height="156"/>
            <path d="M55.344 60.304C58.992 60.88 62.304 62.368 65.28 64.768C68.352 67.168 70.752 70.144 72.48 73.696C74.304 77.248 75.216 81.04 75.216 85.072C75.216 90.16 73.92 94.768 71.328 98.896C68.736 102.928 64.944 106.144 59.952 108.544C55.056 110.848 49.248 112 42.528 112H5.08801V11.632H41.088C47.904 11.632 53.712 12.784 58.512 15.088C63.312 17.296 66.912 20.32 69.312 24.16C71.712 28 72.912 32.32 72.912 37.12C72.912 43.072 71.28 48.016 68.016 51.952C64.848 55.792 60.624 58.576 55.344 60.304ZM18.192 54.976H40.224C46.368 54.976 51.12 53.536 54.48 50.656C57.84 47.776 59.52 43.792 59.52 38.704C59.52 33.616 57.84 29.632 54.48 26.752C51.12 23.872 46.272 22.432 39.936 22.432H18.192V54.976ZM41.376 101.2C47.904 101.2 52.992 99.664 56.64 96.592C60.288 93.52 62.112 89.248 62.112 83.776C62.112 78.208 60.192 73.84 56.352 70.672C52.512 67.408 47.376 65.776 40.944 65.776H18.192V101.2H41.376Z"/>
            <path d="M129.257 113.296C121.865 113.296 115.145 111.616 109.097 108.256C103.145 104.896 98.4405 100.144 94.9845 94C91.6245 87.76 89.9445 80.56 89.9445 72.4C89.9445 64.336 91.6725 57.232 95.1285 51.088C98.6805 44.848 103.481 40.096 109.529 36.832C115.577 33.472 122.345 31.792 129.833 31.792C137.321 31.792 144.089 33.472 150.137 36.832C156.185 40.096 160.937 44.8 164.393 50.944C167.945 57.088 169.721 64.24 169.721 72.4C169.721 80.56 167.897 87.76 164.249 94C160.697 100.144 155.849 104.896 149.705 108.256C143.561 111.616 136.745 113.296 129.257 113.296ZM129.257 101.776C133.961 101.776 138.377 100.672 142.505 98.464C146.633 96.256 149.945 92.944 152.441 88.528C155.033 84.112 156.329 78.736 156.329 72.4C156.329 66.064 155.081 60.688 152.585 56.272C150.089 51.856 146.825 48.592 142.793 46.48C138.761 44.272 134.393 43.168 129.689 43.168C124.889 43.168 120.473 44.272 116.441 46.48C112.505 48.592 109.337 51.856 106.937 56.272C104.537 60.688 103.337 66.064 103.337 72.4C103.337 78.832 104.489 84.256 106.793 88.672C109.193 93.088 112.361 96.4 116.297 98.608C120.233 100.72 124.553 101.776 129.257 101.776Z"/>
            <path d="M220.934 31.792C227.75 31.792 233.702 33.28 238.79 36.256C243.974 39.232 247.814 42.976 250.31 47.488V33.088H263.558V113.728C263.558 120.928 262.022 127.312 258.95 132.88C255.878 138.544 251.462 142.96 245.702 146.128C240.038 149.296 233.414 150.88 225.83 150.88C215.462 150.88 206.822 148.432 199.91 143.536C192.998 138.64 188.918 131.968 187.67 123.52H200.63C202.07 128.32 205.046 132.16 209.558 135.04C214.07 138.016 219.494 139.504 225.83 139.504C233.03 139.504 238.886 137.248 243.398 132.736C248.006 128.224 250.31 121.888 250.31 113.728V97.168C247.718 101.776 243.878 105.616 238.79 108.688C233.702 111.76 227.75 113.296 220.934 113.296C213.926 113.296 207.542 111.568 201.782 108.112C196.118 104.656 191.654 99.808 188.39 93.568C185.126 87.328 183.494 80.224 183.494 72.256C183.494 64.192 185.126 57.136 188.39 51.088C191.654 44.944 196.118 40.192 201.782 36.832C207.542 33.472 213.926 31.792 220.934 31.792ZM250.31 72.4C250.31 66.448 249.11 61.264 246.71 56.848C244.31 52.432 241.046 49.072 236.918 46.768C232.886 44.368 228.422 43.168 223.526 43.168C218.63 43.168 214.166 44.32 210.134 46.624C206.102 48.928 202.886 52.288 200.486 56.704C198.086 61.12 196.886 66.304 196.886 72.256C196.886 78.304 198.086 83.584 200.486 88.096C202.886 92.512 206.102 95.92 210.134 98.32C214.166 100.624 218.63 101.776 223.526 101.776C228.422 101.776 232.886 100.624 236.918 98.32C241.046 95.92 244.31 92.512 246.71 88.096C249.11 83.584 250.31 78.352 250.31 72.4Z"/>
            <path d="M282.246 72.256C282.246 64.192 283.878 57.136 287.142 51.088C290.406 44.944 294.87 40.192 300.534 36.832C306.294 33.472 312.726 31.792 319.83 31.792C325.974 31.792 331.686 33.232 336.966 36.112C342.246 38.896 346.278 42.592 349.062 47.2V5.44H362.31V112H349.062V97.168C346.47 101.872 342.63 105.76 337.542 108.832C332.454 111.808 326.502 113.296 319.686 113.296C312.678 113.296 306.294 111.568 300.534 108.112C294.87 104.656 290.406 99.808 287.142 93.568C283.878 87.328 282.246 80.224 282.246 72.256ZM349.062 72.4C349.062 66.448 347.862 61.264 345.462 56.848C343.062 52.432 339.798 49.072 335.67 46.768C331.638 44.368 327.174 43.168 322.278 43.168C317.382 43.168 312.918 44.32 308.886 46.624C304.854 48.928 301.638 52.288 299.238 56.704C296.838 61.12 295.638 66.304 295.638 72.256C295.638 78.304 296.838 83.584 299.238 88.096C301.638 92.512 304.854 95.92 308.886 98.32C312.918 100.624 317.382 101.776 322.278 101.776C327.174 101.776 331.638 100.624 335.67 98.32C339.798 95.92 343.062 92.512 345.462 88.096C347.862 83.584 349.062 78.352 349.062 72.4Z"/>
            <path d="M380.999 72.256C380.999 64.192 382.631 57.136 385.895 51.088C389.159 44.944 393.623 40.192 399.287 36.832C405.047 33.472 411.431 31.792 418.439 31.792C425.351 31.792 431.351 33.28 436.439 36.256C441.527 39.232 445.319 42.976 447.815 47.488V33.088H461.063V112H447.815V97.312C445.223 101.92 441.335 105.76 436.151 108.832C431.063 111.808 425.111 113.296 418.295 113.296C411.287 113.296 404.951 111.568 399.287 108.112C393.623 104.656 389.159 99.808 385.895 93.568C382.631 87.328 380.999 80.224 380.999 72.256ZM447.815 72.4C447.815 66.448 446.615 61.264 444.215 56.848C441.815 52.432 438.551 49.072 434.423 46.768C430.391 44.368 425.927 43.168 421.031 43.168C416.135 43.168 411.671 44.32 407.639 46.624C403.607 48.928 400.391 52.288 397.991 56.704C395.591 61.12 394.391 66.304 394.391 72.256C394.391 78.304 395.591 83.584 397.991 88.096C400.391 92.512 403.607 95.92 407.639 98.32C411.671 100.624 416.135 101.776 421.031 101.776C425.927 101.776 430.391 100.624 434.423 98.32C438.551 95.92 441.815 92.512 444.215 88.096C446.615 83.584 447.815 78.352 447.815 72.4Z"/>
            <path d="M523.095 31.648C532.695 31.648 540.471 34.576 546.423 40.432C552.375 46.192 555.351 54.544 555.351 65.488V112H542.391V67.36C542.391 59.488 540.423 53.488 536.487 49.36C532.551 45.136 527.175 43.024 520.359 43.024C513.447 43.024 507.927 45.184 503.799 49.504C499.767 53.824 497.751 60.112 497.751 68.368V112H484.647V33.088H497.751V44.32C500.343 40.288 503.847 37.168 508.263 34.96C512.775 32.752 517.719 31.648 523.095 31.648Z"/>
        </mask>
        <path d="M55.344 60.304C58.992 60.88 62.304 62.368 65.28 64.768C68.352 67.168 70.752 70.144 72.48 73.696C74.304 77.248 75.216 81.04 75.216 85.072C75.216 90.16 73.92 94.768 71.328 98.896C68.736 102.928 64.944 106.144 59.952 108.544C55.056 110.848 49.248 112 42.528 112H5.08801V11.632H41.088C47.904 11.632 53.712 12.784 58.512 15.088C63.312 17.296 66.912 20.32 69.312 24.16C71.712 28 72.912 32.32 72.912 37.12C72.912 43.072 71.28 48.016 68.016 51.952C64.848 55.792 60.624 58.576 55.344 60.304ZM18.192 54.976H40.224C46.368 54.976 51.12 53.536 54.48 50.656C57.84 47.776 59.52 43.792 59.52 38.704C59.52 33.616 57.84 29.632 54.48 26.752C51.12 23.872 46.272 22.432 39.936 22.432H18.192V54.976ZM41.376 101.2C47.904 101.2 52.992 99.664 56.64 96.592C60.288 93.52 62.112 89.248 62.112 83.776C62.112 78.208 60.192 73.84 56.352 70.672C52.512 67.408 47.376 65.776 40.944 65.776H18.192V101.2H41.376Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M129.257 113.296C121.865 113.296 115.145 111.616 109.097 108.256C103.145 104.896 98.4405 100.144 94.9845 94C91.6245 87.76 89.9445 80.56 89.9445 72.4C89.9445 64.336 91.6725 57.232 95.1285 51.088C98.6805 44.848 103.481 40.096 109.529 36.832C115.577 33.472 122.345 31.792 129.833 31.792C137.321 31.792 144.089 33.472 150.137 36.832C156.185 40.096 160.937 44.8 164.393 50.944C167.945 57.088 169.721 64.24 169.721 72.4C169.721 80.56 167.897 87.76 164.249 94C160.697 100.144 155.849 104.896 149.705 108.256C143.561 111.616 136.745 113.296 129.257 113.296ZM129.257 101.776C133.961 101.776 138.377 100.672 142.505 98.464C146.633 96.256 149.945 92.944 152.441 88.528C155.033 84.112 156.329 78.736 156.329 72.4C156.329 66.064 155.081 60.688 152.585 56.272C150.089 51.856 146.825 48.592 142.793 46.48C138.761 44.272 134.393 43.168 129.689 43.168C124.889 43.168 120.473 44.272 116.441 46.48C112.505 48.592 109.337 51.856 106.937 56.272C104.537 60.688 103.337 66.064 103.337 72.4C103.337 78.832 104.489 84.256 106.793 88.672C109.193 93.088 112.361 96.4 116.297 98.608C120.233 100.72 124.553 101.776 129.257 101.776Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M220.934 31.792C227.75 31.792 233.702 33.28 238.79 36.256C243.974 39.232 247.814 42.976 250.31 47.488V33.088H263.558V113.728C263.558 120.928 262.022 127.312 258.95 132.88C255.878 138.544 251.462 142.96 245.702 146.128C240.038 149.296 233.414 150.88 225.83 150.88C215.462 150.88 206.822 148.432 199.91 143.536C192.998 138.64 188.918 131.968 187.67 123.52H200.63C202.07 128.32 205.046 132.16 209.558 135.04C214.07 138.016 219.494 139.504 225.83 139.504C233.03 139.504 238.886 137.248 243.398 132.736C248.006 128.224 250.31 121.888 250.31 113.728V97.168C247.718 101.776 243.878 105.616 238.79 108.688C233.702 111.76 227.75 113.296 220.934 113.296C213.926 113.296 207.542 111.568 201.782 108.112C196.118 104.656 191.654 99.808 188.39 93.568C185.126 87.328 183.494 80.224 183.494 72.256C183.494 64.192 185.126 57.136 188.39 51.088C191.654 44.944 196.118 40.192 201.782 36.832C207.542 33.472 213.926 31.792 220.934 31.792ZM250.31 72.4C250.31 66.448 249.11 61.264 246.71 56.848C244.31 52.432 241.046 49.072 236.918 46.768C232.886 44.368 228.422 43.168 223.526 43.168C218.63 43.168 214.166 44.32 210.134 46.624C206.102 48.928 202.886 52.288 200.486 56.704C198.086 61.12 196.886 66.304 196.886 72.256C196.886 78.304 198.086 83.584 200.486 88.096C202.886 92.512 206.102 95.92 210.134 98.32C214.166 100.624 218.63 101.776 223.526 101.776C228.422 101.776 232.886 100.624 236.918 98.32C241.046 95.92 244.31 92.512 246.71 88.096C249.11 83.584 250.31 78.352 250.31 72.4Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M282.246 72.256C282.246 64.192 283.878 57.136 287.142 51.088C290.406 44.944 294.87 40.192 300.534 36.832C306.294 33.472 312.726 31.792 319.83 31.792C325.974 31.792 331.686 33.232 336.966 36.112C342.246 38.896 346.278 42.592 349.062 47.2V5.44H362.31V112H349.062V97.168C346.47 101.872 342.63 105.76 337.542 108.832C332.454 111.808 326.502 113.296 319.686 113.296C312.678 113.296 306.294 111.568 300.534 108.112C294.87 104.656 290.406 99.808 287.142 93.568C283.878 87.328 282.246 80.224 282.246 72.256ZM349.062 72.4C349.062 66.448 347.862 61.264 345.462 56.848C343.062 52.432 339.798 49.072 335.67 46.768C331.638 44.368 327.174 43.168 322.278 43.168C317.382 43.168 312.918 44.32 308.886 46.624C304.854 48.928 301.638 52.288 299.238 56.704C296.838 61.12 295.638 66.304 295.638 72.256C295.638 78.304 296.838 83.584 299.238 88.096C301.638 92.512 304.854 95.92 308.886 98.32C312.918 100.624 317.382 101.776 322.278 101.776C327.174 101.776 331.638 100.624 335.67 98.32C339.798 95.92 343.062 92.512 345.462 88.096C347.862 83.584 349.062 78.352 349.062 72.4Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M380.999 72.256C380.999 64.192 382.631 57.136 385.895 51.088C389.159 44.944 393.623 40.192 399.287 36.832C405.047 33.472 411.431 31.792 418.439 31.792C425.351 31.792 431.351 33.28 436.439 36.256C441.527 39.232 445.319 42.976 447.815 47.488V33.088H461.063V112H447.815V97.312C445.223 101.92 441.335 105.76 436.151 108.832C431.063 111.808 425.111 113.296 418.295 113.296C411.287 113.296 404.951 111.568 399.287 108.112C393.623 104.656 389.159 99.808 385.895 93.568C382.631 87.328 380.999 80.224 380.999 72.256ZM447.815 72.4C447.815 66.448 446.615 61.264 444.215 56.848C441.815 52.432 438.551 49.072 434.423 46.768C430.391 44.368 425.927 43.168 421.031 43.168C416.135 43.168 411.671 44.32 407.639 46.624C403.607 48.928 400.391 52.288 397.991 56.704C395.591 61.12 394.391 66.304 394.391 72.256C394.391 78.304 395.591 83.584 397.991 88.096C400.391 92.512 403.607 95.92 407.639 98.32C411.671 100.624 416.135 101.776 421.031 101.776C425.927 101.776 430.391 100.624 434.423 98.32C438.551 95.92 441.815 92.512 444.215 88.096C446.615 83.584 447.815 78.352 447.815 72.4Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M523.095 31.648C532.695 31.648 540.471 34.576 546.423 40.432C552.375 46.192 555.351 54.544 555.351 65.488V112H542.391V67.36C542.391 59.488 540.423 53.488 536.487 49.36C532.551 45.136 527.175 43.024 520.359 43.024C513.447 43.024 507.927 45.184 503.799 49.504C499.767 53.824 497.751 60.112 497.751 68.368V112H484.647V33.088H497.751V44.32C500.343 40.288 503.847 37.168 508.263 34.96C512.775 32.752 517.719 31.648 523.095 31.648Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why have you specified the same css property twice with different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `:first-of-type` to select the first path , it is Not the first child (`:nth-child(1)`) mask is the first child

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
background-color: black;

}

#logo {
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 20%;
}

#logo path:first-of-type {
    stroke-dasharray: 200px;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="logo" width="561" height="156" viewBox="0 0 561 156" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <mask id="path-1-outside-1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0.0880127" y="0.440002" width="561" height="156" fill="black">
            <rect fill="white" x="0.0880127" y="0.440002" width="561" height="156"/>
            <path d="M55.344 60.304C58.992 60.88 62.304 62.368 65.28 64.768C68.352 67.168 70.752 70.144 72.48 73.696C74.304 77.248 75.216 81.04 75.216 85.072C75.216 90.16 73.92 94.768 71.328 98.896C68.736 102.928 64.944 106.144 59.952 108.544C55.056 110.848 49.248 112 42.528 112H5.08801V11.632H41.088C47.904 11.632 53.712 12.784 58.512 15.088C63.312 17.296 66.912 20.32 69.312 24.16C71.712 28 72.912 32.32 72.912 37.12C72.912 43.072 71.28 48.016 68.016 51.952C64.848 55.792 60.624 58.576 55.344 60.304ZM18.192 54.976H40.224C46.368 54.976 51.12 53.536 54.48 50.656C57.84 47.776 59.52 43.792 59.52 38.704C59.52 33.616 57.84 29.632 54.48 26.752C51.12 23.872 46.272 22.432 39.936 22.432H18.192V54.976ZM41.376 101.2C47.904 101.2 52.992 99.664 56.64 96.592C60.288 93.52 62.112 89.248 62.112 83.776C62.112 78.208 60.192 73.84 56.352 70.672C52.512 67.408 47.376 65.776 40.944 65.776H18.192V101.2H41.376Z"/>
            <path d="M129.257 113.296C121.865 113.296 115.145 111.616 109.097 108.256C103.145 104.896 98.4405 100.144 94.9845 94C91.6245 87.76 89.9445 80.56 89.9445 72.4C89.9445 64.336 91.6725 57.232 95.1285 51.088C98.6805 44.848 103.481 40.096 109.529 36.832C115.577 33.472 122.345 31.792 129.833 31.792C137.321 31.792 144.089 33.472 150.137 36.832C156.185 40.096 160.937 44.8 164.393 50.944C167.945 57.088 169.721 64.24 169.721 72.4C169.721 80.56 167.897 87.76 164.249 94C160.697 100.144 155.849 104.896 149.705 108.256C143.561 111.616 136.745 113.296 129.257 113.296ZM129.257 101.776C133.961 101.776 138.377 100.672 142.505 98.464C146.633 96.256 149.945 92.944 152.441 88.528C155.033 84.112 156.329 78.736 156.329 72.4C156.329 66.064 155.081 60.688 152.585 56.272C150.089 51.856 146.825 48.592 142.793 46.48C138.761 44.272 134.393 43.168 129.689 43.168C124.889 43.168 120.473 44.272 116.441 46.48C112.505 48.592 109.337 51.856 106.937 56.272C104.537 60.688 103.337 66.064 103.337 72.4C103.337 78.832 104.489 84.256 106.793 88.672C109.193 93.088 112.361 96.4 116.297 98.608C120.233 100.72 124.553 101.776 129.257 101.776Z"/>
            <path d="M220.934 31.792C227.75 31.792 233.702 33.28 238.79 36.256C243.974 39.232 247.814 42.976 250.31 47.488V33.088H263.558V113.728C263.558 120.928 262.022 127.312 258.95 132.88C255.878 138.544 251.462 142.96 245.702 146.128C240.038 149.296 233.414 150.88 225.83 150.88C215.462 150.88 206.822 148.432 199.91 143.536C192.998 138.64 188.918 131.968 187.67 123.52H200.63C202.07 128.32 205.046 132.16 209.558 135.04C214.07 138.016 219.494 139.504 225.83 139.504C233.03 139.504 238.886 137.248 243.398 132.736C248.006 128.224 250.31 121.888 250.31 113.728V97.168C247.718 101.776 243.878 105.616 238.79 108.688C233.702 111.76 227.75 113.296 220.934 113.296C213.926 113.296 207.542 111.568 201.782 108.112C196.118 104.656 191.654 99.808 188.39 93.568C185.126 87.328 183.494 80.224 183.494 72.256C183.494 64.192 185.126 57.136 188.39 51.088C191.654 44.944 196.118 40.192 201.782 36.832C207.542 33.472 213.926 31.792 220.934 31.792ZM250.31 72.4C250.31 66.448 249.11 61.264 246.71 56.848C244.31 52.432 241.046 49.072 236.918 46.768C232.886 44.368 228.422 43.168 223.526 43.168C218.63 43.168 214.166 44.32 210.134 46.624C206.102 48.928 202.886 52.288 200.486 56.704C198.086 61.12 196.886 66.304 196.886 72.256C196.886 78.304 198.086 83.584 200.486 88.096C202.886 92.512 206.102 95.92 210.134 98.32C214.166 100.624 218.63 101.776 223.526 101.776C228.422 101.776 232.886 100.624 236.918 98.32C241.046 95.92 244.31 92.512 246.71 88.096C249.11 83.584 250.31 78.352 250.31 72.4Z"/>
            <path d="M282.246 72.256C282.246 64.192 283.878 57.136 287.142 51.088C290.406 44.944 294.87 40.192 300.534 36.832C306.294 33.472 312.726 31.792 319.83 31.792C325.974 31.792 331.686 33.232 336.966 36.112C342.246 38.896 346.278 42.592 349.062 47.2V5.44H362.31V112H349.062V97.168C346.47 101.872 342.63 105.76 337.542 108.832C332.454 111.808 326.502 113.296 319.686 113.296C312.678 113.296 306.294 111.568 300.534 108.112C294.87 104.656 290.406 99.808 287.142 93.568C283.878 87.328 282.246 80.224 282.246 72.256ZM349.062 72.4C349.062 66.448 347.862 61.264 345.462 56.848C343.062 52.432 339.798 49.072 335.67 46.768C331.638 44.368 327.174 43.168 322.278 43.168C317.382 43.168 312.918 44.32 308.886 46.624C304.854 48.928 301.638 52.288 299.238 56.704C296.838 61.12 295.638 66.304 295.638 72.256C295.638 78.304 296.838 83.584 299.238 88.096C301.638 92.512 304.854 95.92 308.886 98.32C312.918 100.624 317.382 101.776 322.278 101.776C327.174 101.776 331.638 100.624 335.67 98.32C339.798 95.92 343.062 92.512 345.462 88.096C347.862 83.584 349.062 78.352 349.062 72.4Z"/>
            <path d="M380.999 72.256C380.999 64.192 382.631 57.136 385.895 51.088C389.159 44.944 393.623 40.192 399.287 36.832C405.047 33.472 411.431 31.792 418.439 31.792C425.351 31.792 431.351 33.28 436.439 36.256C441.527 39.232 445.319 42.976 447.815 47.488V33.088H461.063V112H447.815V97.312C445.223 101.92 441.335 105.76 436.151 108.832C431.063 111.808 425.111 113.296 418.295 113.296C411.287 113.296 404.951 111.568 399.287 108.112C393.623 104.656 389.159 99.808 385.895 93.568C382.631 87.328 380.999 80.224 380.999 72.256ZM447.815 72.4C447.815 66.448 446.615 61.264 444.215 56.848C441.815 52.432 438.551 49.072 434.423 46.768C430.391 44.368 425.927 43.168 421.031 43.168C416.135 43.168 411.671 44.32 407.639 46.624C403.607 48.928 400.391 52.288 397.991 56.704C395.591 61.12 394.391 66.304 394.391 72.256C394.391 78.304 395.591 83.584 397.991 88.096C400.391 92.512 403.607 95.92 407.639 98.32C411.671 100.624 416.135 101.776 421.031 101.776C425.927 101.776 430.391 100.624 434.423 98.32C438.551 95.92 441.815 92.512 444.215 88.096C446.615 83.584 447.815 78.352 447.815 72.4Z"/>
            <path d="M523.095 31.648C532.695 31.648 540.471 34.576 546.423 40.432C552.375 46.192 555.351 54.544 555.351 65.488V112H542.391V67.36C542.391 59.488 540.423 53.488 536.487 49.36C532.551 45.136 527.175 43.024 520.359 43.024C513.447 43.024 507.927 45.184 503.799 49.504C499.767 53.824 497.751 60.112 497.751 68.368V112H484.647V33.088H497.751V44.32C500.343 40.288 503.847 37.168 508.263 34.96C512.775 32.752 517.719 31.648 523.095 31.648Z"/>
        </mask>
        <path d="M55.344 60.304C58.992 60.88 62.304 62.368 65.28 64.768C68.352 67.168 70.752 70.144 72.48 73.696C74.304 77.248 75.216 81.04 75.216 85.072C75.216 90.16 73.92 94.768 71.328 98.896C68.736 102.928 64.944 106.144 59.952 108.544C55.056 110.848 49.248 112 42.528 112H5.08801V11.632H41.088C47.904 11.632 53.712 12.784 58.512 15.088C63.312 17.296 66.912 20.32 69.312 24.16C71.712 28 72.912 32.32 72.912 37.12C72.912 43.072 71.28 48.016 68.016 51.952C64.848 55.792 60.624 58.576 55.344 60.304ZM18.192 54.976H40.224C46.368 54.976 51.12 53.536 54.48 50.656C57.84 47.776 59.52 43.792 59.52 38.704C59.52 33.616 57.84 29.632 54.48 26.752C51.12 23.872 46.272 22.432 39.936 22.432H18.192V54.976ZM41.376 101.2C47.904 101.2 52.992 99.664 56.64 96.592C60.288 93.52 62.112 89.248 62.112 83.776C62.112 78.208 60.192 73.84 56.352 70.672C52.512 67.408 47.376 65.776 40.944 65.776H18.192V101.2H41.376Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M129.257 113.296C121.865 113.296 115.145 111.616 109.097 108.256C103.145 104.896 98.4405 100.144 94.9845 94C91.6245 87.76 89.9445 80.56 89.9445 72.4C89.9445 64.336 91.6725 57.232 95.1285 51.088C98.6805 44.848 103.481 40.096 109.529 36.832C115.577 33.472 122.345 31.792 129.833 31.792C137.321 31.792 144.089 33.472 150.137 36.832C156.185 40.096 160.937 44.8 164.393 50.944C167.945 57.088 169.721 64.24 169.721 72.4C169.721 80.56 167.897 87.76 164.249 94C160.697 100.144 155.849 104.896 149.705 108.256C143.561 111.616 136.745 113.296 129.257 113.296ZM129.257 101.776C133.961 101.776 138.377 100.672 142.505 98.464C146.633 96.256 149.945 92.944 152.441 88.528C155.033 84.112 156.329 78.736 156.329 72.4C156.329 66.064 155.081 60.688 152.585 56.272C150.089 51.856 146.825 48.592 142.793 46.48C138.761 44.272 134.393 43.168 129.689 43.168C124.889 43.168 120.473 44.272 116.441 46.48C112.505 48.592 109.337 51.856 106.937 56.272C104.537 60.688 103.337 66.064 103.337 72.4C103.337 78.832 104.489 84.256 106.793 88.672C109.193 93.088 112.361 96.4 116.297 98.608C120.233 100.72 124.553 101.776 129.257 101.776Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M220.934 31.792C227.75 31.792 233.702 33.28 238.79 36.256C243.974 39.232 247.814 42.976 250.31 47.488V33.088H263.558V113.728C263.558 120.928 262.022 127.312 258.95 132.88C255.878 138.544 251.462 142.96 245.702 146.128C240.038 149.296 233.414 150.88 225.83 150.88C215.462 150.88 206.822 148.432 199.91 143.536C192.998 138.64 188.918 131.968 187.67 123.52H200.63C202.07 128.32 205.046 132.16 209.558 135.04C214.07 138.016 219.494 139.504 225.83 139.504C233.03 139.504 238.886 137.248 243.398 132.736C248.006 128.224 250.31 121.888 250.31 113.728V97.168C247.718 101.776 243.878 105.616 238.79 108.688C233.702 111.76 227.75 113.296 220.934 113.296C213.926 113.296 207.542 111.568 201.782 108.112C196.118 104.656 191.654 99.808 188.39 93.568C185.126 87.328 183.494 80.224 183.494 72.256C183.494 64.192 185.126 57.136 188.39 51.088C191.654 44.944 196.118 40.192 201.782 36.832C207.542 33.472 213.926 31.792 220.934 31.792ZM250.31 72.4C250.31 66.448 249.11 61.264 246.71 56.848C244.31 52.432 241.046 49.072 236.918 46.768C232.886 44.368 228.422 43.168 223.526 43.168C218.63 43.168 214.166 44.32 210.134 46.624C206.102 48.928 202.886 52.288 200.486 56.704C198.086 61.12 196.886 66.304 196.886 72.256C196.886 78.304 198.086 83.584 200.486 88.096C202.886 92.512 206.102 95.92 210.134 98.32C214.166 100.624 218.63 101.776 223.526 101.776C228.422 101.776 232.886 100.624 236.918 98.32C241.046 95.92 244.31 92.512 246.71 88.096C249.11 83.584 250.31 78.352 250.31 72.4Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M282.246 72.256C282.246 64.192 283.878 57.136 287.142 51.088C290.406 44.944 294.87 40.192 300.534 36.832C306.294 33.472 312.726 31.792 319.83 31.792C325.974 31.792 331.686 33.232 336.966 36.112C342.246 38.896 346.278 42.592 349.062 47.2V5.44H362.31V112H349.062V97.168C346.47 101.872 342.63 105.76 337.542 108.832C332.454 111.808 326.502 113.296 319.686 113.296C312.678 113.296 306.294 111.568 300.534 108.112C294.87 104.656 290.406 99.808 287.142 93.568C283.878 87.328 282.246 80.224 282.246 72.256ZM349.062 72.4C349.062 66.448 347.862 61.264 345.462 56.848C343.062 52.432 339.798 49.072 335.67 46.768C331.638 44.368 327.174 43.168 322.278 43.168C317.382 43.168 312.918 44.32 308.886 46.624C304.854 48.928 301.638 52.288 299.238 56.704C296.838 61.12 295.638 66.304 295.638 72.256C295.638 78.304 296.838 83.584 299.238 88.096C301.638 92.512 304.854 95.92 308.886 98.32C312.918 100.624 317.382 101.776 322.278 101.776C327.174 101.776 331.638 100.624 335.67 98.32C339.798 95.92 343.062 92.512 345.462 88.096C347.862 83.584 349.062 78.352 349.062 72.4Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M380.999 72.256C380.999 64.192 382.631 57.136 385.895 51.088C389.159 44.944 393.623 40.192 399.287 36.832C405.047 33.472 411.431 31.792 418.439 31.792C425.351 31.792 431.351 33.28 436.439 36.256C441.527 39.232 445.319 42.976 447.815 47.488V33.088H461.063V112H447.815V97.312C445.223 101.92 441.335 105.76 436.151 108.832C431.063 111.808 425.111 113.296 418.295 113.296C411.287 113.296 404.951 111.568 399.287 108.112C393.623 104.656 389.159 99.808 385.895 93.568C382.631 87.328 380.999 80.224 380.999 72.256ZM447.815 72.4C447.815 66.448 446.615 61.264 444.215 56.848C441.815 52.432 438.551 49.072 434.423 46.768C430.391 44.368 425.927 43.168 421.031 43.168C416.135 43.168 411.671 44.32 407.639 46.624C403.607 48.928 400.391 52.288 397.991 56.704C395.591 61.12 394.391 66.304 394.391 72.256C394.391 78.304 395.591 83.584 397.991 88.096C400.391 92.512 403.607 95.92 407.639 98.32C411.671 100.624 416.135 101.776 421.031 101.776C425.927 101.776 430.391 100.624 434.423 98.32C438.551 95.92 441.815 92.512 444.215 88.096C446.615 83.584 447.815 78.352 447.815 72.4Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        <path d="M523.095 31.648C532.695 31.648 540.471 34.576 546.423 40.432C552.375 46.192 555.351 54.544 555.351 65.488V112H542.391V67.36C542.391 59.488 540.423 53.488 536.487 49.36C532.551 45.136 527.175 43.024 520.359 43.024C513.447 43.024 507.927 45.184 503.799 49.504C499.767 53.824 497.751 60.112 497.751 68.368V112H484.647V33.088H497.751V44.32C500.343 40.288 503.847 37.168 508.263 34.96C512.775 32.752 517.719 31.648 523.095 31.648Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `:first-*` pseudoelement works for `path`. It seems that not...

What about little workaround?

```
#logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 200px;
    stroke-dasharray: 50px;
}

#logo path ~ path {
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
}
```